# Touch Gesture Recognizer to clear screen of random function

Tags: swift, xcode

I am building a collage in Xcode with a set background image and a random int function to display an image.

I tried using a tapGestureRecognizer to 1) display the random image and 2) clear the screen after using self.clearScreen. The images are displaying but they do not disappear when the next image is displayed.

```swift
import UIKit
import C4

class WorkSpace: CanvasController {

    override func setup() {


        var myRandomNumber: Int?

        //Background Image
        let background = Image("background")
        background?.constrainsProportions = true
        background?.width = self.canvas.width
        background?.height = self.canvas.height

        self.canvas.add(background)

        canvas.addTapGestureRecognizer { (locations, center, state) in
            self.clearScreen
            myRandomNumber = random(below: 4)
                }
            }

           if myRandomNumber == 1 {
            let tree = Image("Tree")
                tree?.constrainsProportions = true
                tree?.width = self.canvas.width
                tree?.origin = Point(0.0, self.canvas.height/2.0)
                self.canvas.add(tree)
                print("number1")
            }
            if myRandomNumber == 2 {
                let boy = Image("boy")
                boy?.constrainsProportions = true
                boy?.width = self.canvas.width
                boy?.origin = Point(0.0, self.canvas.height/2.0)
                self.canvas.add(boy)
            }
            if myRandomNumber == 3 {
                let woman = Image("woman")
                woman?.constrainsProportions = true
                woman?.width = self.canvas.width
                woman?.height = self.canvas.height
                self.canvas.add(woman)
           }
    }
}
```

I would like the screen to clear the pictures and replace with another.

```
func clearScreen() { 
    for view in self.view.subView { 
        view.removeFromSuperView()
    }
}
```

Comment: What’s the code for clearscreen?

Comment: In my teachers code which we did together he filled out self.clearScreen and it worked for him. I feel I have replicated the code exactly so Im super confused on why its not working.

Comment: Can you post the code for self.clearScreen?

Comment: func clearScreen(){
        for view in self.view.subView{
            view.removeFromSuperView()
        }
        }

Comment: Can you add it to the original question instead of in the comments?

Comment: The hard part is Im having trouble getting it to work in the code

Comment: at a quick glance, you're adding the images to self.canvas, but attempting to remove them from self.view.subviews.   I'm not familiar with what canvas is though or how its set up.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the C4 pod [docs](https://github.com/C4Labs/C4iOS/blob/master/C4/UI/View.swift): 
Check the view hierarchy after adding to canvas

```
/// Adds a view to the end of the receiver’s list of subviews.
/// When working with C4, use this method to add views because it handles the addition of both UIView and View.
public func add<T>(_ subview: T?) {...}
```

**And then try removing subviews with their supplied methods:**

`````
/// Unlinks the view from the receiver and its window, and removes it from the responder chain.
/// Calling this method removes any constraints that refer to the view you are removing, or that refer to any view in the
/// subtree of the view you are removing.
/// When working with C4, use this method to add views because it handles the removal of both UIView and View.
/// ````
/// let v = View(frame: Rect(0,0,100,100))
/// let subv = View(frame: Rect(25,25,50,50))
/// v.add(subv)
/// v.remove(subv)
/// ````
/// - parameter subview:    The view to be removed.
public func remove<T>(_ subview: T?) {
    if let v = subview as? UIView {
        v.removeFromSuperview()
    } else if let v = subview as? View {
        v.view.removeFromSuperview()
    } else {
        fatalError("Can't remove subview of class `\(type(of: subview))`")
    }
}
`````